# Is there Mist version without Coinbase support?

Tags: mist, wallets, coinbase

I wanted to update Ethereum Wallet, but in the changelog I read that they made some kind of deal with Coinbase (that the Ethereum Foundation has no money from, apparently) and added direct support for that one exchange. I do not want to be a part of that, so I ask: Is there an up-to-date version of the Ethereum Wallet that does not this built in (an official fork, perhaps)?

And there are two downloads on the download page: Ethereum Wallet and Mist. I suppose they both have this support, so what is the difference between them? I have searched, but they are mostly mentioned as if they were the same.

Comment: Your concern is valid, but a couple relevant points: 
1. Mist has supported the Shapeshift integration (which is awesome) to enable bitcoin to ether purchases for quite a while now.
2. The Coinbase integration is quite specialized, allowing for credit card purchases without signing in to an account. I don't think any other exchange has a similarly user friendly integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official version that does not include this functionality, but if you're so inclined it is possible to fork it and edit the functionality out.

As for the difference between Mist and Wallet, Mist is a web browser that supports Ethereum. It can interact with any DApp, including but not limited to the official wallet.

The wallet is just a version of Mist that is locked to the official wallet and cannot be used to surf the internet.

Comment: I feared as much. Indeed I could invest unreasonable time and effort into forking the repository, but that is not an option, since I doubt I would be able to maintain it. Thanks for explaining the difference.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can tell,

it's only used to see the rates between ETH/BTC/USD etc
but cant actually convert/sell ETH for BTC from he interface

Comment: No, it uses the Coinbase buy widget: https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/buy-widget.